# Print specific row with awk from output of df -h

Tags: linux, awk, grep

When I run df -h I see:

```
/dev/sda2                     46G  3.2G   41G   8% /
udev                          24G  4.0K   24G   1% /dev
tmpfs                        9.5G   10M  9.5G   1% /run
none                         5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                          24G     0   24G   0% /run/shm
/dev/mapper/DG9999-lvDG9999   82T   75T  7.5T  91% /DG9999
/dev/sda3                     20G  445M   19G   3% /home
clamfs                        82T   75T  7.5T  91% /DG9999/clamfs
```

I'm using this command:

```
 df -h / | grep -v Filesystem | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/%//g'
```

At the moment the output shows me the 5th column in the first line of the `df -h` output which is `8`. How can I specify that I am interested in the 6th line of the output so that the output shows `91`.

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that you run `df -h` and then try to parse `df -h /` (which restricts it to the filesystem hosting '/')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the appropriate file system (or mount point):

```
df -h /DG9999 | grep -v Filesystem | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/%//g'
```

When parsing `df`’s output on most Linux systems, you should use the `-P` option to ensure that each file system’s information is kept on a single line:

```
df -hP /DG9999 | grep -v Filesystem | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/%//g'
```

You can combine all the output manipulation to use just AWK:

```
df -hP /DG9999 | awk '!/Filesystem/ { print substr($5, 1, length($5) - 1) }'
```

On any recent GNU setup you can also run

```
df --output=pcent /DG9999 | sed '1d;s/%//'
```

Comment: @don_crissti I like the use of `--output`, thanks!

Comment: no prob; it's pretty cool, yeah... I missed the fact that OP wants only the number - in that case piping to `tr -dc '[^[:digit:]]'` instead of `sed` would be infinitesimally faster/more efficient as it doesn't require a regex :P